# Как сделать страницу основной (Spring MVC + Security)

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

Когда я запускаю страницу у меня выводится страница логина, а я хочу чтобы после запуска проекта сразу высветилась "allStudents.jsp"

AllStudents.JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
        <title>Все студенты</title>
    </head>
    <body>



        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="it">
            <h3>Список всех студентов</h3>
            ${message}

            <br>
            <br>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Имя</th>

                        <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
                        <th scope="col">Фото</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>${student.name}</td>
                            <td>${student.surname}</td>

                            <td><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;" /></td>

                            <td>
                                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Редактировать</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Удалить</button>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить студента</button></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Security Config

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}1234").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Web-MVC-Config

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "adil.java.schoolmaven")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size:1024}")

    private int maxUploadFileSize;

    @Bean

    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css");
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();

        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadFileSize * 1024);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationController

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AuthorizationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
        m.addObject("title", "Вы успешно вошли");
        m.addObject("message", "home");
        m.setViewName("admin");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect: allStudents");
    }
}
```

Student Controller

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

Comment: у вас сейча на доступ к любой странице кроме логина есть права только у админа. `http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`

Comment: Как можно сделать чтобы allStudents тоже права были у всех, потому что я хочу в allStudents сделать кнопку для входа через логин и пароль. В общем как можно сделать так чтобы allStudents появился сразу после запуска